# Joomla Migration resulting JFactory failure

Tags: php, joomla

I have migrated my joomla to another server by copying all files, restoring data and restoring all linking. It shows on the page well but one of the modules, Contact Form, has been broken. Had a closer look, found the execution of the following line failed.

```
$mail = JFactory::getMailer();
```

Internal Server Error 500 was shown. Checked the manual it should be a built-in API from joomla I've no result log showing the exact problem. Anyone has similar experience, would be able to give any clue?

Comment: If the `JFactory` class wasn't being called, your site would be throwing errors left, right and center. I think you will find something else is causing the problem

Comment: I have checked other functions from JFactory, like getconfig, they're working well except getMailer()

Comment: Hmm odd. Have you ensured you're using the latest version of Joomla? Have you by any chance modified any core Joomla files?

Comment: No I have just directly copied everything. The config from JFactory shows difference, but I can't think of any clue that would fail getMailer().

Comment: There is nothing faulty with the JMailer function and I don't think there ever has been. I think the issues will be caused by something else in the code. Can you please provide the full code you're using? Please also ask this question (with your full code) the to [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions) site :)